# Finding $f(x)$ for Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm not really sure what to do whatsoever, the  3 questions after this are based on the same concept so knowing this should allow me to do the rest. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum can be written as $$\frac{4}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{1 + \frac{4k}{n}} = \frac{5 - 1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n f\left( 1 + \frac{4k}{n}\right)$$ Thus $b = 5$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. For further informations, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Right_Riemann_Sum).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The sum can be  written as $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k)\,\Delta\mkern1mux_k$, with $x_k=\dfrac kn$ and $\Delta x_k=\dfrac 1n$. From this you can deduce the function $f$ and the bounds, obtained $k=0$  and $k=n$  respectively.