# Finding f(x) Rieman Sum

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

This is 1 of the 3 remaining questions I have left due for my webwork which is due tonight. If someone can please show me how to do this I can do the following two which are based on the same concept. People have told me how to partially do it but I just can't really tie it to this question. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Pretty hard Riemann sum problems for what seems to be an entry level calculus class. The answers will be fairly similar though. What have you practiced prior? You're going to have to resort to the definition of the riemann sum for these

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding $f(x)$ for Riemann sum](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930822/finding-fx-for-riemann-sum)

Comment: Oh do I? No we didn't go through this in class so im confused. I'm planning on getting a tutor next week so i just want to make sure I get these right and then I can have him explain it to me if anything.

Answer (score 1):

Right Riemann sums are of the form: $\sum_{i=1}^nf(a+i\Delta x)*\Delta x$, where $\Delta x = \frac {b-a}n$, $b$ is your right endpoint, $a$ is your left endpoint, and $n$ is the number of rectangles you have. To fit this to your problem, look for what specifically is the $\Delta x$. The $\Delta x$ should be the same in every term.

**Example:** I am using a different function set and numbers to avoid any cheating.

$$\sin\left(0+\frac2n\right)*\left(\frac2n\right)+\sin\left(0+\frac4n\right)*\left(\frac2n\right)+\sin\left(0+\frac6n\right)*\left(\frac2n\right)+...+\sin\left(0+\frac{2n}n\right)*\left(\frac2n\right)$$

In this case, $a=0$, $\Delta x=\frac2n=\frac{b-0}n$, and $b=2$. You can find out what $\Delta x$ is by looking at the term that remains constant throughout the sum and by the difference between the arguments of the function, i.e. $\frac4n-\frac2n=\frac2n$. You can then use $\Delta x$ to find $b$ by adding it to $a$.

Comment: Well change in x is (b-4)/n. I don't know how this helps

Comment: I should have said this earlier: $\Delta x$ is a constant. It does not change from each term of the sum. In other words, you should be able to rewrite the Riemann sum as $\Delta x\sum_{i=1}^nf(a+i\Delta x)$ and factor out the $\Delta x$.